# How does thickness of film affect the quality of the a thin film polarizer?

Tags: optics, polarization, design

I have limited optical experience as a biomedical engineering student and am currently trying to spec out a polarizing filter. I understand that there are performance parameters, such as extinction ratio, transmission, and acceptance angle, which are usually specified by the manufacturer. These filters are sold at various thicknesses, and I'm wondering how the thickness will affect the performance of the filter. Ideally, I'm trying to minimize any sort of blur, and I suspect the thickness of the film has an impact on this, but I cannot find anything to substantiate that.

Do you have any suggestions for selecting a proper polarizing film? I would ideally like to minimize cost, as well. I don't know where to begin.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that thickness alone is the determining factor of how good the optical quality of a polarizing filter is. In fact, it may be way down on the list of determining factors. The material that the filter is made out of is probably much more important. Glass polarizing filters for SLR cameras and high-end microscopes are much better quality than cheap plastic polarizing filters.

Comment: Surface quality (and how parallel the faces of the filter are) would be more important than thickness.