# Effect of thickening polariser on intensity pattern

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction, intensity

I've performed an experiment where microwaves were sent through a polariser of varying thickness, composed of $11$ slits (width and spacing both $6$ mm).

To vary the thickness of the polariser, this experiment was performed with 1, 2 and 3 *identical* polarisers stacked on top of each other (and aligned, of course).

I've had a look around (including at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296594/how-does-thickness-of-film-affect-the-quality-of-the-a-thin-film-polarizer), but I don't think their question was quite the same as mine) and can't find any theory that covers how the thickness of the actual polariser (not number of slits or spacing) affects the intensity pattern.

Could someone give an explanation please, and potentially also a source or two?

Comment: What was the result of your experiment?

Comment: @Farcher The $I_0 \cos^2 \theta$ relationship held for each thickness, but the maximum intensity varied. The double polariser had the greatest intensity, with the single polariser intensity being somewhat lower. For three polarisers, the maximum intensity dropped off drastically.